# memory use of STL data structures, windows vs. linux

Tags: c++, stl, memory-management

I have a program that heavily uses `std::map`. Under Windows, much more memory is used as under Linux. Has anyone an idea why this happens?

Linux:
`Last process took 42.31 s and used not more than 909 MB (RSS 900 MB) of memory`

Windows:
`Last process took 75.373 s and used not more than 1394 MB (RSS 1395 MB) of memory`

I use gcc 4.4.3 and the VS 2010 C++ compiler on the command line, with release settings.

EDIT:
Sorry for answering the questions that late...

The code looks like this:

```
enum Symbol {
    ...
}

class GraphEntry {

    public:

    ...

    virtual void setAttribute (Symbol name, Value * value) = 0;

    const Value * attribute (Symbol name) const;

    private:

    std::map<Symbol, Attribute> m_attributes;
};

class Attribute {

    public:

    Attribute (Symbol name, Value * val);

    ...

    Symbol name () const;

    Value * valuePointer () const;

    void setValuePointer (Value * p);

    private:

    Symbol m_name;

    Value * m_value;
};

class Graph : public GraphEntry {

    ...

    public:

    Node * newNode (...);

    Graph * newSubGraph (...);

    Edge * newEdge (...);

    ...

    setSomeAttribute (int x);

    setSomeOtherAttribute (float f);

    ...

    private:

    std::vector<GraphEntry *> m_entries;
};
```

The whole thing describes a graph structure, which can hold some attributes on its nodes and edges. `Value`is just a base class, and the derived classes can hold values with arbitrary types, like `int` or `std::string`.

EDIT 2:
Under Windows, I use the following flags: `-DRELEASE -DNDEBUG -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE -DNOMINMAX /O2 /MD /Gy /EHsc`

EDIT 3:
The memory usage is read from a /proc file under linux (like `memuse`).
Under Windows, some WinAPI functions are called, but I am not the expert for this, so that's all what I can say about it.

EDIT 4:
Using `/GS-` and `-D_SECURE_SCL` results in `Last process took 170.281 s and used not more than 1391 MB (RSS 1393 MB) of memory`

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?  If so, which version?  Are you in debug?

Comment: How did you measure memory usage?

Comment: Code or it didn't happen.

Comment: How do you measure memory usage, what does your code look like, and how do you call the compiler (GCC doesn't have "release settings")

Comment: Memory usage depends on compiler flags, so please show us all the flags you are passing to the compiler.

Comment: Are you EVER going to answer the question about using checked iterators?

Comment: @swegi: Please take a look at my answer where I demonstrate the reason quantitatively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll observe that memory usage on Windows is somewhere between 1 and 2 times greater. Heap algorithms aside, Windows [`malloc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ycsb6wwf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), and subsequently any data structures allocated on the heap via `new` (such as `std::map`'s nodes with the default allocator type), are aligned to 16 bytes. On Linux, [glibc defaults to 8 byte alignment](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_31.html). Assuming some smoothing in differences due to fragmentation, optimization reaping of unused pages etc. you can expect the differences to become less apparent

A quick check of your code indicates map key and value types should be 4 and 8 bytes respectively (`Symbol` and `Attribute`). These will round up to 8 bytes on Linux, and 16 bytes on Windows. You should have an equal number of map nodes, at least in the MSVC implementation, these look to consume a minimum of 22 bytes, which MSVC will expand to 32 due to its member alignment rules, which is also its malloc granularity. GCC will expand its to 24, meaning an approximate total of 48 bytes in MSVC to GCC/Linux' 32 *per node*. **Roughly 50% more memory usage on Windows**.

Here's the node structure used in MSVC, I can look up the GCC equivalent if you are interested:

```
struct _Node
    {   // tree node
    _Nodeptr _Left; // left subtree, or smallest element if head
    _Nodeptr _Parent;   // parent, or root of tree if head
    _Nodeptr _Right;    // right subtree, or largest element if head
    value_type _Myval;  // the stored value, unused if head
    char _Color;    // _Red or _Black, _Black if head
    char _Isnil;    // true only if head (also nil) node
```

I'll add for those who are unfamiliar with how memory usage works, there are several factors at play:

- Memory is allocated in chunks rounding up to the next multiple of the alignment for the allocation mechanism used. For the heap, the `malloc()` alignment rules are in use (unless you subvert the usual heap or use some other allocator than the default).
- Virtual memory is "provided" by the system in chunks known as pages, integer multiples of the frame size, which is beyond the scope of this question. This has a minor effect on the answer, as the memory usage is so massive compared with the page size in question (4K), and the page size in turn is so massive compared to the alignments in use (8 and 16).

Comment: I should add the increased run time on Windows is a combination of the increased size of the structures, meaning less caching can occur, and instruction optimization differences in the compilers used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The increased runtime is also due to a slower machine used for windows development.

Answer (score 7):

Each compiler is shipped with its own implementation of the STL, therefore you are comparing:

- GCC STL + Linux allocation routines
- VC++ STL + Windows allocation routines

It's quite difficult to draw a meaningful comparison here because you don't know which of the allocation routine or STL implementation (or possibly both) is actually responsible.

I do suppose that you are not comparing a 32-bits program with a 64-bits program, since this would be even less meaningful.

Answer (score 6):

Some versions of VC++ use checked iterators (_SECURE_SCL) in release builds, too. [VC2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965(VS.80).aspx) and [VC2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965(VS.90).aspx) have them turned on by default. 
VC2010 disables them [by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985896.aspx)

Depending on your compiler, that could be another thing to check (and turn off).

Comment: +1. This solved it for me when I was called to solve a simular case.

Comment: @swegi: please comment on whether this applies to you, and if so how the memory compared afterwards...

Answer (score 0):

Did you execute the test in release or debug mode under windows? STL in debug mode does a lot of extra checking; maybe it also uses more memory to be able to perform all checks.

Answer (score 0):

For VC++ try to use /GS- command line switch.

Answer (score 0):

When you say memory used is "not more than" are you referring to the peak memory usage or the mean memory usage during the lifetime of the application?

Make sure if the memory allocated by your application using 'new' or 'malloc' or any other memory allocation library call are released back using 'delete' or 'free' or any equivalent library call.

In Linux, you can use valgrind and check for memory leaks.